# Use puppet to make changes to ip route and sysctl

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

I have two changes to `ip route` & `sysctl` that disable tcp slow start. 
Here’s how I do it

```
ip route show
```

*Make a note of the line starting with default.*

Pick up the IP from the default line and run

```
sudo ip route change default via $ip_address dev eth0 initcwnd 12 
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle=0
```

How can I create a puppet script out of this? One that can be deployed to many machines of the same type – CentOS 6

**Edit:** 
Added bounty to get a working example for

```
sudo ip route change default via $ip_address dev eth0 initcwnd 12
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going off of larsks answer, if you have static ip addresses, place this in /sbin/ifup-local

```
#!/bin/sh

GATEWAY=`ip route| awk '/^def/{print $3}'`
DEFGWDEV=`ip route| awk '/^def/{print $5}'`

if [ "$1" = $DEFGWDEV ]; then
  ip route change default via $GATEWAY dev $DEFGWDEV initcwnd 12
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

The `sysctl` side was covered in this post: [Set sysctl.conf parameters with Puppet](https://serverfault.com/questions/361876/set-sysctl-conf-parameters-with-puppet).

Puppet's [example for networking](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Network_Interface_Templates_Patterns) also leverages [Augeas](http://augeas.net/).

Edit:
You're on CentOS, so remember that you need to make these routes persistent... Is the safer approach to make the change in a file, verify, then restart the network interface? This assumes `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethX` use since you're using `via` syntax. The `ip route` command seems to be your goal since you want to change the initial congestion window (initcwnd). I would seriously separate that into another option because setting the default gateway by itself should be handled by the OS network scripts/kickstart/build process.

---

Now for a totally different solution:

I like Puppet for some things. [Network configs and sysctl values are not among them.](https://serverfault.com/questions/414758/what-should-not-be-managed-by-puppet) With EL6 systems, you have the ability to use the [tuned-adm framework](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/tuned-adm.html) to make these system changes on the fly in an easy and consistent manner. The servers I manage sometimes need 30+ `sysctl` and `sysfs` changes before going into production. I used to manage that manually, then with Puppet... but with EL6, I create a [*tuned* profile](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/main-analyzeperf-tuned.html) with all of the requisite tweaks and scripts, manage the profiles and their distribution with Puppet, and control the `tuned` daemon with Puppet.

Given that, just move your `ip` script and `sysctl` values in a custom profile and go from there. Much cleaner.

Comment: Hard a hard time trying to figure out the networking bit. Even explored https://github.com/AbbyEdwards/puppet-iproute2facts 
Can you help me with the ip route?

Comment: You're on CentOS, so remember that you need to make these routes persistent, right? Is the safer approach to make the change in a file, verify, then restart the network interface? This assumes `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethX` use.

Answer (score 6):

If you are obtaining your internet address using DHCP (which is suggested by your question), then you can use `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks` to run shell commands after `dhclient` configures your interface.  You'll have access to a number of variables provided by dhclient, including `$router`.  You can use this to run:

```
ip route change default via $router dev $interface initcwnd 12
```

You would install this script with a normal Puppet `file` resource:

```
file { '/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks':
owner => root,
group => root,
mode => 0755,
source => 'puppet:///.../dhclient-exit-hooks',
}
```

And the file contents would probably look something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$interface" = eth0 ]; then
  ip route change default via ${new_routers%% *} dev $interface initcwnd 12 
fi
```

If you're *not* using DHCP, you can do something similar.  The normal `ifup` script runs `/sbin/ifup-local` after configuring the interface, and you could use this to run the `ip` command.  In this case, you could get the address of the default gateway simply by sourcing in the interface configuration in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (and your Puppet `file` resource would install `/sbin/ifup-local`).